# pandas dataframe how to remove values from cell that is a list based on other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe with 2 columns that represent a list:

```
a. b.  vals.        locs
1. 2. [1,2,3,4,5].  [2,3]
5  1. [1,7,2,4,9].  [0,1]
8. 2. [1,9,4,7,8].  [3]
```

I want, for each row, exclude from the columns vals all the locations that are in locs.
so I will get:

```
a. b.  vals.        locs.   new_vals
1. 2. [1,2,3,4,5].  [2,3].  [1,2,5]
5  1. [1,7,2,4,9].  [0,1].  [2,4,9]
8. 2. [1,9,4,7,8].  [3].    [1,9,4,8]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `enumerate` and converting values to `set`s:

```
df['new_vals'] = [[z for i, z in enumerate(x) if i not in y]
                              for x, y in zip(df['vals'], df['locs'].apply(set))]
print (df)
   a  b             vals    locs      new_vals
0  1  2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [2, 3]     [1, 2, 5]
1  5  1  [1, 7, 2, 4, 9]  [0, 1]     [2, 4, 9]
2  8  2  [1, 9, 4, 7, 8]     [3]  [1, 9, 4, 8]
```

Comment: using set this way will compute it at each iteration (making it potentially slower than not using a set)

Comment: I note that you already updated the first time based on my answer, no? ;)

Comment: solution with sets is next step.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension with an internal filter based on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
df['new_vals'] = [[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if i not in b]
                  for a,b in zip(df['vals'], df['locs'])]
```

however this will become quickly inefficient when b get large.

A much better approach would be to use [python sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) that enable a fast (O(1) complexity) identification of membership:

```
df['new_vals'] = [[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if i not in S]
                  for a,b in zip(df['vals'], df['locs']) for S in [set(b)]]
```

output:

```
   a  b             vals    locs      new_vals
0  1  2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [2, 3]     [1, 2, 5]
1  5  1  [1, 7, 2, 4, 9]  [0, 1]     [2, 4, 9]
2  8  2  [1, 9, 4, 7, 8]     [3]  [1, 9, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a function that works on row,

```
def func(row):
    ans = [v for v in row['vals'] if row['vals'].index(v) not in row['locs']]
    return ans
```

The call this function for each row using apply.

```
df['new_value'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

This will work well, if the lists are short.